# Allowing people to vote on comments

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, privileges

As we know that people with low reputation can not vote comments or upvote answers. What is the logic behind this?

We have a basic system which tells users if the comment or answer is useful or not, so if people below 15 reputation will be allowed then the site will benefit from it; won't it?

Comment: [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347/260312) on MSE.

Comment: At last, Why do people down-vote a question without explaining as to why?

Comment: @Mr.Helpy why do people not search before asking?

Comment: How would the site benefit from a lot of input from people who don't really know how to use the site yet?

Comment: ..or a lot of input from people who really do know how to use the site, after all, they have a pool of 50 script-maintained puppet accounts.

Comment: @Mr.Helpy like on the main site, you're supposed to do your research on topics before asking. You will get downvoted on meta for asking stuff that has ALREADY been discussed. At least downvotes here don't cost rep. Oh and PLEASE don't start asking for justification for downvotes.... let's just not go there... this never ends well

Comment: In addition to @Patrice comment votes on META commonly reflect simple disagreement with proposal. Also this particular post seem to be hitting on all reasons: no research for existing question, no clear explanation why proposal would be useful and proposal that does not have any support on META.

Comment: Lol, I am embarassed by my own question, sorry guys won't make the mistake again. I wish I could downvote my own question. Now don't start down voting this comment too

Comment: @Patrice yes I am thankful that it doesn't cost rep

Comment: _"Now don't start down voting this comment too"_ Don't worry, comments can't be downvoted, only flagged. :) I don't think that one's in danger of it.

Comment: @Kendra Oh thank you, what a relief ;)

Comment: I think my question will have a half centuary of down votes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voting on Stack Overflow (and on any other site in the Stack Exchange network) is a quality control mechanism. That exists because as we learn from the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Good answers are voted up and rise to the top. *The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.*

I assume you can fill in what happens with questions and answers that are not useful, badly researched, unclear, homework dump, effortless crap.

We simply don't trust any newcomer to be able to correctly judge what *good* (and *bad*) means on this site. Therefor we rather have you watch and learn before we trust you with that important and responsible task.

Up voting the wrong posts has more impact then you can imagine. Future visitors might assume that the question or answer is OK, when it isn't. That's a bad experience for them. Bad posts that get up voted might be selected as an audit for reviewers who get highly confused if a bad post turns out to be up voted.

To be part of this community we expect you to care about the post on this site. Your votes should indicate that. We first want to see a bit if you're up to that responsibility and not start voting because you like the name of the user or because the OP has nice avatar. Stack Overflow is not about people, it is about Questions and Answers and the voting is its quality control system.